# how to find weight vector from the libsvm model file?

Tags: libsvm

I have the following model file from LIBSVM:

```
svm_type c_svc kernel_type linear nr_class 2 total_sv 3 rho 0.0666415
label 1 -1 nr_sv 2 1 SV
0.004439511653718091 1:4.5 2:0.5 
0.07111595083031433 1:2 2:2 
-0.07555546248403242 1:-0.5 2:-2.5
```

My question is how do I figure out the weight vector from this information?

Answer (score 0):

The weights of the support vectors are the first numbers on each of the support vector lines (the last three). Despite using a linear kernel, libsvm is for general kernel SVMs, so it isn't storing a weight vector and bias explicitly.

If you know you want a linear kernel, and you want that information, you can use liblinear (from the same folks as libsvm). Given this trivial data:

```
1 1:1 2:1
0 1:-1 2:-1
```

you can get this model, which has explicit weight and bias:

```
solver_type L2R_L2LOSS_SVC_DUAL
nr_class 2
label 1 0
nr_feature 2
bias -1
w
0.4327936 
0.4327936
```

Comment: Thanks, also how do I set the parameter c (I want c to be large enough so that there won't be misclassification at all) such that i get different weight vectors. Thanks.